# Write a python function that reads content from a csv file performs some calculations then outputs the results in a html table on a seperate html page

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary, file

I have to perform calculations for each column of data from a CSV file. I plan to read the file as a dictionary so that the headers are the keys and each column of data becomes values under their respective keys. I currently have lines of code that store the keys as a list and a code string that outputs values of only that key using the .get() function if I specify and index the critical list. My current issue is how to iterate through each key so that it performs statistical operations on all of its values at once and then moves to the following key. I haven't attempted the HTML side of the project yet, but I am assuming if the calculations for each column are done at the same time, I can store it in its cell then,  as it moves onto the following key to start its calculations on the data a code will be written so that. It, where it will store the analysis, will move one cell forward. **The project only allows me to import CSV**. The code is in the next section below.

Current code:

```
def hehehe(file: str, html_file: str, title: str = None):
    with open(file, 'r') as cal_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(cal_file)
        grouped_data = {}
        for i in reader:
            # this code call on each key individually so that I can get the collective values of each key separately when i put a braket and a number in the bracket
            keys = list(i.keys())
            # what is inside this print outputs the value of each column depending on what the key is
            calc = i.get(keys)          
            print(i.get(keys))
```

Comment: `i.get(keys)` doesn't make sense. The argument to `i.get()` must be a single key.

Comment: Have you considered loading the CSV into a pandas dataframe? Then you can perform statistical operations on columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is put each column into a key of `grouped_data`.

```
def hehehe(file: str, html_file: str, title: str = None):
    grouped_data = {}
    with open(file, 'r') as cal_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(cal_file)
        for i in reader:
            for k, v in i.items():
                grouped_data.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    keys = list(grouped_data.keys())
    # now you can get keys from `keys`, and use grouped_data[key] to get a list of all the values of that key
```